# Why do Windows and Linux machines handle Spring application integration tests differently?

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration-testing

(Pardon my choice of diction - I am inexperienced with Java / Spring / PowerMock / SoapUI).

I made a code change that leads to a database call, and now I have failing integration tests around the Spring application. The structure is similar to this:

```
// Integration tests class
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyConfigurationClass.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@PrepareForTest({..., MyDbConnector.class, ...})   // MyDbConnector is a wrapper around JdbcTemplate

...

@Rule
public PowerMockRule powerMockRule = new PowerMockRule();

@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

...

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ...
    whenNew(MyDbConnector.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mock(MyDbConnector.class));
    ...
}

// MyConfigurationClass.java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ...,
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = someClass.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = someOtherClass.class)
    }
)
public final class MyConfigurationClass {}
```

Before my change, the build ran successfully on Linux and Windows.
After my change, the build runs successfully on Windows, but fails on Linux. The build on Linux appears to attempt to connect to the database by calling a method in `MyDbConnector`, but fails to execute the SQL query. Since `MyDbConnector` should be mocked out, it shouldn't even enter into the real method.

Why does the Windows maven build (seem to) mock out `MyDbConnector` successfully, while the Linux maven build does not? I have confirmed the test runs on both OS's.

Potentially important notes:

- I have two integration test classes, one that only tests against Spring, and one that uses `WsdlProjectRunner` to run SoapUI tests against Spring
- I tried the build on two different Linux machines. On one machine, only the SoapUI tests failed, but on another, SoapUI and non-SoapUI tests fail.

EDIT: with the help of a co-worker, instead of:

```
@PrepareForTest({..., MyDbConnector.class, ...})
```

I added:

```
@PrepareForTest({..., MyDbConnector.class, ClassThatUsesMyDbConnector.class, ...})
```

That solves our problem, but does not answer the question, so I'll leave it open.

Comment: Are you using a powermock rule? Do you have a `mockStatic(MyDbConnector.class)`, the full code for the setup method might help getting an answer

Comment: No I don't. When I tried adding `mockStatic(MyDbConnector.class)` before the `whenNew()`, I got a `null` pointer exception. I'll try it again to get the full error.

Comment: Powermock needs a specific runner `PowerMockRunner` or a junit `@Rule`, you should read the doc. I don't see the whole picture but I would advise using either "mocks" (and just that) **or** spring in tests (with an in memory DB for example)

Comment: @RC. Sorry trying to pick it up as I go. I added the missing `@Rule`s annotation. Are these the docs you were referring to? https://github.com/jayway/powermock

Comment: yes, the wiki contains the doc: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki

Comment: When I add `mockStatic(MyDbConnector.class)` before the `whenNew()`, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when trying to initialize `MyDbConnector`.

Comment: My advice: remove powermock, make MyDbConnector a spring bean and leverage that

Comment: Not sure if you have more thoughts @RC., but we managed to get the build running (updated answer).